# Cross pages music player

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I had an idea before and I thought that it won't be executed without an iframe or Ajax calls.

I couldn't keep an MP3 file or a radio channel working after changing the URL in the website, for example,

> website.com/profile

To

> website.com/news

The whole page will change of course, and the MP3, or radio have to load again.

But, I realized that SoundCloud has this feature - after playing a music, when exploring the site, the music keeps working, and when you comeback to the music page, it will be like you never left the page.

Also, Facebook uses this in the chat on the right. When you change the pages, most of the time, the chat won't get hurt by the change, meaning that the chat keeps working as if you're on the same page and never changed it.

Comment: iframes, or ajax calls to replace parts of the main page with the "next" page.

Comment: in the case i want , the whole page will change, and not request is made inside a div or an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Iframe and AJAX call is a only way to do it.
Ajax Call is my favorite:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "My URL",
    async: true
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#mydiv").html(result);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use an iframe or a div, i want the whole page and link will change like in soundcloud . Please look at the question carefully

Comment: I encourage people to use "AJAX". Read my answer more carefully.

Comment: And you can't say "only way" , because other sites are using what i'm asking for.

Comment: soundcloud.com uses AJAX call to change full page content and leave music player online. You can search AJAX call in soundcloud JS files.